# How to combine this two into one so that the function can run at the same time

Tags: php, html, forms

My code now is in separate conditions. If I submit my form `without insert any data`, it must be `two warning` come out; if I insert `no.of people`, and submit it will show the `required of age`; if I `insert the age` and submit it will show the `required of people`.

`But now` when i submit my code without anything, it `only show the warning of age`? How to fix it by `only php` so that when i submit the form without anythings and two warning will pop out and call must be fill in this two fields

This code is process.php

```
<?php
$errors = [];
if (empty($_POST['people'])) {
    $errors[] = 'people';
}
if (empty($_POST['age'])) {
    $errors[] = 'age';
}

if (count($errors)) {
    header('Location: form.php?error=' . implode(",", $errors));
}

$person = $_POST['people'];
$ages = $_POST['age'];
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$date = date('H:i, jS F Y');

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Result of Carbon Footprint Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

echo "<p>Calculation processed at ".date('H:i, jS F Y')."</p>";
echo "<p>The calculation is as follow: </p>";

if ($person > 0) {
    echo $person." person in household<br/>";
}
if ($ages > 0) {
    echo $ages." age<br/>";
}

$outputstring = $date."\t".$person." \t".$ages." \t";

@ $fp = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/car/ttl.txt", 'ab');

flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

if (!$fp) {
  echo "<p><strong> Your order could not be processed at this time.
        Please try again later.</strong></p></body></html>";
  exit;
}

  // write the file
fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring));
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);

echo "<p>Calculation complete.</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is form.php

```
<?php
$errors = isset($_REQUEST['errors']) ? $_REQUEST['errors'] : '';
if ($errors) {
    $arr = explode(",", $errors);
    foreach ($arr as $error) {
        if ($error == 'people') {
            echo "you need to enter name<br>";
        }
        if ($error == 'age') {
            echo "you need to enter age<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <h1>Members</h1>
       <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="process.php">
            <tr>
                <td >Number of Person</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="people" >
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" size="18" maxlength="18">
                <span class="error"></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></th>
                  </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for `exp9.php` is relevant but you can send all errors as json or as comma separated string. Using GET parameters for this purpose isn't the ideal thing though. Maybe $_SESSION would have been better.

Validation part:

```php
$errors = [];
if (empty($_POST['people'])) {
    $errors[] = 'people';
}
if (empty($_POST['age'])) {
    $errors[] = 'age';
}

if (count($errors)) {
    header('Location: exp9.php?error=' . implode(",", $errors));
}
```

exp9.php:

```php
$errors = isset($_REQUEST['errors']) ? $_REQUEST['errors'] : '';
if ($errors) {
    $arr = explode(",", $errors);
    foreach ($arr as $error) {
        if ($error == 'name') {
            echo "you need to enter name<br>";
        }
        if ($error == 'age') {
            echo "you need to enter age<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Update: The entire form page with errors should look like this (needs refactoring)

```html
<?php
$errors = isset($_REQUEST['errors']) ? $_REQUEST['errors'] : '';
$error_people = "";
$error_age = "";
if ($errors) {
    $arr = explode(",", $errors);
    foreach ($arr as $error) {
        if ($error == 'people') {
            $error_people = "you need to enter name";
        }
        if ($error == 'age') {
            $error_age = "you need to enter age";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <h1>Members</h1>
       <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="process.php">
            <tr>
                <td >Number of Person</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="people" >
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_people; ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" size="18" maxlength="18">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_age; ?></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></th>
                  </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Comment: hi, the code is work, but the echo word does not show up in the form, may i know how to fix this problem. Thx you very muc

Comment: how does your form look like?

Comment: https://vscode.dev/github/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/docs/datascience/form.php#L49

Comment: here is my code can u able to view it?

Comment: above is my form.php

Comment: https://vscode.dev/github/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/docs/datascience/process.php#L7

Comment: this is process.php link

Comment: can you post your code here? you can [edit] your question

Comment: i have edited the code already. so sorry for keep disturbing you ......